# fetch price from database and multiply with dynamically given quantity and display total through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The given select options are printing products name from database. The products table also contain saleprice column against every product I have to multiply that saleprice with dynamically given quantity and to display sudden when quantity is entered. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<select name="product_id" class="form-control" class="select" ID="select" > 
                 <option disabled selected>-- Select Product --</option>
                 <!-- to retrive data from database and show into dropdown  -->
                <?php
                 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'login');
                 $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * From products where deleted=0");  // Use select query here 
                 while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
                 {
                echo "<option value=". $data['id'] ." >" .$data['name'] ."    </option>";  // displaying data in option menu
                 
                 }  
             ?>  
          </select>
          <label> Quantity: </label>
          <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" id="productqty" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required=""  /> 
          <input type="hidden" class='total' name="total[]" id="total_amount"  placeholder="Total Amount" />
```

the code I tried, but this doesn't work, now what to do?

```
    $(document).on('change, focusout', '#select,#productqty', function(){
    var oproductname = $(this).val();
    var productQty = parseInt($('#productqty').val());
    var productPrice = parseFloat($('#select').find(':selected').data('price'));
    var totalAmount = productQty * productPrice ;
    if(!isNaN(totalAmount)) { 
        $('#total_amount').val(totalAmount );
    }

});
```

Comment: It is because `data('price')` is not defined in your list of options. You need to assign the `data-price` attribute when creating the product options.

Comment: @ajayramgarhia echo"<option data-price=".$data['saleprice']." value=". $data['id'] .">" .$data['name'] ." </option>";  but nothing displayed. is there any need to change in jquery?

Comment: Can you make sure `jquery` library is loaded. I have created a fiddle for you with test data and it is working with jquery. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qd4pfeyn/2/)

Comment: fiddle is working but  when quantity is entered then after one click total is printed...is there an issue of focusout?i want when quantity is entered sudden displayed the total

Comment: `focusout` event works when you move the focus out of the element. If you need to show the `total` when `qty` is entered you need to use the `input` event

Comment: as the variable totalamount stores the result in jquery,so when we need to insert data on submit this variable is used or i can again fetch data using query and then multiply with quantity in php?

Comment: The following code `$('#total_amount').val(totalAmount )` already update the html form with the required information. So on form submit, you can use the input to get the required result. But I am not sure why you are using the quantity and total value as array `name="quantity[]"` and `name="total[]"`. As the code is not suitable to store multiple values there.

Comment: @ajayramgarhia thanks i have completed my task through your help

Comment: thanks for the feedback, can you close this question if you have achieve your result.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `data('price')` is not defined in your list of options. You need to assign the `data-price` attribute when creating the product options.

Can you make sure `jquery` library is loaded. I have created a fiddle for you with test data and it is working with jquery. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qd4pfeyn/2/)